# No camel consumer available for routes of type direct-vm when testing

Tags: java, testing, apache-camel, camel-test

I'm working with unit tests using Camel and, When I execute [this test](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter9/advicewith/src/test/java/camelinaction/AdviceWithMockEndpointsTest.java) from Camel In Action repository it works perfectly but when I change the route type from SEDA to **direct-vm** it fails with the following message:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.directvm.DirectVmConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct-vm://camel. Exchange[ID....

The difference of these 2 types, SEDA and direct-vm, is that the first is asynchronous and the second is synchronous. Is that the reason why the test fails? How can I make the test work for **direct-vm** type of routes?

I'm using JDK 1.8 and Camel 2.25.2

**UPDATE:** I have found an issue with the *mockEndpoints()* method inside the *adviceWith*, the routes are not being mocked. This is what is printed in the logs when I launch the test:

```
2021-07-20 16:27:36.501  INFO 31220 --- [           main] org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition   : Adviced route before/after as XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="basicRoute">
    <from uri="direct-vm:quotes"/>
    <choice id="choice2">
        <when id="when2">
            <simple>${body} contains 'Camel'</simple>
            <log id="log4" loggingLevel="INFO" message="camel route"/>
            <to id="to11" uri="direct-vm:camel"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise id="otherwise2">
            <log id="log5" loggingLevel="INFO" message="other route"/>
            <to id="to12" uri="direct-vm:other"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="basicRoute">
    <from uri="direct-vm:hitme"/>
    <choice id="choice2">
        <when id="when2">
            <simple>${body} contains 'Camel'</simple>
            <log id="log4" loggingLevel="INFO" message="camel route"/>
            <to id="to11" uri="direct-vm:camel"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise id="otherwise2">
            <log id="log5" loggingLevel="INFO" message="other route"/>
            <to id="to12" uri="direct-vm:other"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

But if I use instead weaveByToUri to mock the routes:

```
weaveByToUri("direct-vm:camel").replace().to("mock:direct-vm:camel");
weaveByToUri("direct-vm:other").replace().to("mock:direct-vm:other");
```

The routes are mocked and the test works:

```
2021-07-20 16:30:42.409  INFO 9920 --- [           main] org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition   : Adviced route before/after as XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="basicRoute">
    <from uri="direct-vm:quotes"/>
    <choice id="choice2">
        <when id="when2">
            <simple>${body} contains 'Camel'</simple>
            <log id="log4" loggingLevel="INFO" message="camel route"/>
            <to id="to11" uri="direct-vm:camel"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise id="otherwise2">
            <log id="log5" loggingLevel="INFO" message="other route"/>
            <to id="to12" uri="direct-vm:other"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="basicRoute">
    <from uri="direct-vm:hitme"/>
    <choice id="choice2">
        <when id="when2">
            <simple>${body} contains 'Camel'</simple>
            <log id="log4" loggingLevel="INFO" message="camel route"/>
            <pipeline>
                <to uri="mock:direct-vm:camel"/>
            </pipeline>
        </when>
        <otherwise id="otherwise2">
            <log id="log5" loggingLevel="INFO" message="other route"/>
            <pipeline>
                <to uri="mock:direct-vm:other"/>
            </pipeline>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

Should It be a bug in the *mockEndpoints* method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use direct-vm in a test you'll have to run another CamelContext that contains consumer for the direct-vm endpoint you want to test. You can do this with Main class.

```java
public class Example extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
        return new DefaultCamelContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
              
                from("direct-vm:helloReceiver")
                    .routeId("helloReceiver")
                    .log("Message received: ${body}")
                    .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testDirectVM() throws Exception{

        RouteBuilder builder = new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
              
                from("direct:helloSender")
                    .routeId("helloSender")
                    .to("direct-vm:helloReceiver");
            }
        };
        
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockEndpoint.message(0).body().isEqualTo("hello");

        Main camelMain = new Main();
        camelMain.addRouteBuilder(builder);
        camelMain.start();

        camelMain.getCamelTemplate()
            .sendBody("direct:helloSender", "hello");

        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

However it would be better to just to use string variable with setter for the direct-vm endpoint that you can easily change to mock endpoint during testing. Give it id and you can use weaveById to make it return whatever you need for the tests.

Comment: Hi Pasi. Thanks for your reply. The thing is, the test should work without having the need to create a new camel context, I mean, if it works correctly for SEDA routes should work as well for DIRECT-VM routes. And I think I found the issue: The _mockEndpoints()_ command inside the _adviceWith_ method is not mocking the endpoints in the route. But by using **weaveByToUri("direct-vm:camel").replace().to("mock:direct-vm:camel");** and **weaveByToUri("direct-vm:other").replace().to("mock:direct-vm:other");** instead the test works. I guess there's a bug in mockEndpoints command for direct-vm routs

Comment: SEDA and direct-vm endpoints differ in visibility. SEDA consumer endpoints are visible in the same camel-context where as direct-vm endpoints are visible inside same JVM.


When you call direct-vm producer endpoint I am guessing that camel just assumes that the endpoint lies in another CamelContext that is running in the same JVM since otherwise you'd be calling direct or seda endpoint.

Comment: Yeah that could be the cause. In my project we have more than one camel context so we need to use direct-vm routes and we are implementing unit tests for those. But perhaps the __mockEndpoints()__ function should contemplate this situation, perhaps could be useful not only for direct or seda but for direct-vm and vm

Comment: Instead of testing these 2 routes on 2 different camel contexts in single test you should test the route that produces the message to direct-vm and the route that consumes the direct-vm message **individually**. Testing both in the same test kinda goes against the best practices when it comes to unit tests.

Comment: Yes you're right about that. I won't test more that one route in a unit test in our project, this was only for testing direct-vm routes only

Answer (score 0):

The error message `No consumers available on endpoint: ...` typically means you have **a producer that sends messages to a synchronous endpoint but no consumer that listens** to this endpoint.

Is it possible that you just changed the producer to `direct-vm`?

By the way: `direct-vm` is typically used to connect Camel routes inside the same JVM but from different Camel contexts. One example for this is between OSGi bundles. If you only have 1 Camel context, just use `direct`.

Comment: Hi Burki. In the project that i work we have more than once camel context, that's why I need to use direct-vm routes.

I haven't changed only the producer but all the routes in the test and the route configuration, from seda to direct-vm and I get the error. I'm testing with the latest camel 2: 2.25.4